# Showing groups of people for the game

Tags: python, math

I need to show the lists of names of 32 people with groups of four. They have to play ten games, but each player has to team up with the person eho they never played with. I was trying this but couldn't figure it out for weeks. Please help.

this is what I tried so far

```
player = 40
k = player//4
for i in range(1, k+1):
    m = 4*i-3
    print(str(i) + " GAME :", end="")
    for j in range(1, k+1):
        print("(", end="")
        print(4*j-4, end="")
        print(", ", end="")
        print((4*j-4+m)%player, end="")
        print(", ", end="")
        print((4*j-4+2*m)%player, end="")
        print(", ", end="")
        print((4*j-4+4*m-1)%player, end="")
        print(")", end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to do, what your intended outcome would look like and specify what exactly you got stuck at?

Comment: Game 1 - Team A - 1,2,3,4  Team B 1,2,3,4 ...   Game 2 - 1,5,9,13 ... Like this